# Me retorna una fecha diferente a la colocada con pikaday

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy desarrollando una app el cual ingreso fecha de nacimiento, lo estoy trabajando con pikaday ya que estoy con livewire y es lo mas sencillo.

Problema: Ingreso una fecha, se guarda perfecto, sin embargo, cuando la voy a mostrar para editar u otras opciones me muestra la fecha con una dia atrasado.

Ejm: Ingreso *Tue Jan 29 2002* y me retorna *Mon Jan 28 2002*.

Asi se guarda:
[image: database]

asi se muestra en el pikaday: [image: pikaday]

> User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'document_type',
        'document_number',
        'salary',
        'profession',
        'professional_commit',
        'personal_commit',
        'record_limit',
        'neighborhood',
        'marital_status',
        'born_date',
        'address',
        'workplace',
        'company',
        'profile_completed',
        'email',
        'records_count',
        'password',
        'facebook_profile',
        'twitter_profile',
        'instagram_profile',
        'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'two_factor_recovery_codes',
        'two_factor_secret',
    ];

}
```

> input donde tengo el pikaday

```
<input id="born_date" wire:model.lazy="record.born_date" x-data x-init="picker = new Pikaday({field: $el, yearRange: [1968, 2005]});" class="mt-1 block w-full form-control shadow-none" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Por lo que vi, es el formato normal que te devuelve al usar "pikaday", deberias cambiar el formato manualmente agregando `format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'`

Comment: La mayoría de las veces que me he encontrado con un problema como este es por diferencias horarias (_timezones_): ¿en qué franja horarias está el usuario, el servidor y la base de datos? ¿qué franja horaria es la que estás usando en el código y en Pikaday?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no sabia que eso implicara en el formato...interesante. Aunque por lo que [veo](https://pikaday.com/) muestra por defecto ese formato

Comment: Aunque tambien en si se debe al propio formato como dices @AlvaroMontoro ya que "2002-01-29" no es igual a "Mon Jan '**28**' 2002". Nose porque, pero tambien me habia pasado lo mismo, ya que por lo visto JS no reconoce el formato "YYYY-MM-DD" sino "YYYY/MM/DD" aunque eso es lo que pienso

Comment: Ya debo trabajarlo con formato "YYYY-MM-DD" porque la app está en producción. Entonces sería que el pikaday cambié el formato. Sin embargo estaba buscando hacerlo, pero no me cambia el formato con la propiedad "format"

Comment: el inconveniente era que no tenia moment.js. Se me habia pasado, gracias por sus comentarios.